# set ssh shell to pwsh in crypto/ssh session

Tags: go, ssh, powershell-core

When creating a ssh session using `x/crypto/ssh`, by default it creates this session and then use bash as the shell.

How do I tell this session to use pwsh instead (we do have it available)? I've searched around and haven't been able to find any real clues on how to do this.

For context. I need to create a ssh session between two docker containers and then execute a powershell script in the target container over the ssh session.

Comment: The shell is determined by the server, not the client. If you want to run a different shell, you will have to execute it yourself.

Comment: I've added this to the sshd_config, `Subsystem powershell /usr/bin/pwsh -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile`, but I have no idea how to then use this when I ssh into that container. I've set the default shell to be pwsh, but I still get bash a the shell when the ssh session connect.

Comment: A subsystem is not the login shell, it's a feature of the ssh server, and must be requested specifically by the client (the most common subsystem being `sftp`). The default login shell for the user is defined per user in the server name service. You can call the subsystem if you want, or you can just request a pty and execute `pwsh` on your own.

Comment: so essentially doing `session.RequestPty`? Is that the same as `ssh -t <username@servername> "pwsh"` ?

Comment: yes, `-t` requests a pty.

Comment: using `session.RequestPty("pwsh", 80, 40, ssh.TerminalModes{})` doesn't return an error, but when I do `session.Run(script)` later on, it returns exist code 127. No idea what I do wrong. Without requesting the Pty, the script is run, but then it uses bash as the shell.

Comment: `pwsh` is not a term type. You probably want `xterm` but I’m not familiar with PowerShell. If you’re executing a script and don’t want an interactive shell, why not just use the default login shell and have that call PowerShell to execute your script?